# .NET Arrays datatypes

Tags: .net, arrays, types

is it possible to store multiple datatypes in an array, if not, what could the reason be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You can make an `object[]` and put anything you want inside of it.

However, you probably shouldn't.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: not trying to implement it but was curious to know if it was possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can store anything you like in an array of objects, but doing so makes me wonder about your design.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your array as an array of `object` then, yes you can store anything in it. You'll have to cast to the desired type when you use it though. I think you really need to understand the concept of type-safety to get your head around why this is a bad idea in most languages.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety